# how to sum number which format #,###.##

Tags: xslt

HI all,

where is possible to sum number which format 1,185.00 in xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"? 
for example:

```
<document>
 <number>1,185.00</number>
 <number>2,000.11</number>
</document>
```

result should be:

```
<document>
 <sum>3185.11</sum>
<document>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try using `translate` and `format-number` when you retrieve resp. when you display the data.

I'm thinking of sg. like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <document>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document/number[1]">
                <xsl:with-param name="val" select="0"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </document>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="number">
        <xsl:param name="val"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(following::number)">
                <sum>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($val + translate(./text(),',',''), '###.##')"/>
                </sum>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following::number">
                    <xsl:with-param name="val" select="$val + translate(./text(),',','')"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which for your input generates the following output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<document>
    <sum>3185.11</sum>
</document>
```

Comment: @rakaszeru: Correct, but remember implict casting: this `$val + number(translate(./text(),',',''))` is the same as this `$val + translate(.,',','')`.

Comment: Thank you, i'll update my answer to be more efficient (i just check it first).